# How to insert HTML element after using Render Angular?

Tags: angular

I have reference to input element:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement;
```

I clone this element and try to append clonned after current:

```
 this.renderer.appendAfter(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.clone);
```

It does not work for me.

I have tried this:

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    const original = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;

    this.cloned = original.cloneNode(true) as HTMLInputElement;
    original.style.display = 'none';
    this.renderer.appendChild(original, this.cloned);
  }
```

Code above inserst input in input not after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further code, I would say the error is connected to the way you clone.

To clone a DOM element, you should use the [DOM cloneNode API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

The following would work:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const original = this._el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    this._renderer.appendChild(original, original.cloneNode(true))
  }
}
```

This would successfully clone the contents of the `AppComponent`.

To append after your own element you should do the following:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const original = this._el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    this._renderer.appendChild(original.parentNode, original.cloneNode(true))
  }
}
```

Do note that cloning a DOM elemnt will not clone a component. This is because we do not clone the `jasascript` that grants the logic to our element, only the pure `HTML` code.

As such, I would not advise using this when cloning more complex elements or elements behaviour.

To be clearer, consider the following example with HTML:

```js
@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<input (keypress)="onBlur($event)>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const original = this._el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    this._renderer.appendChild(original, original.cloneNode(true))
  }

  onBlur(event): void {
    console.log(event)
  } 
}
```

If you were to type in the input of the original element, it would print the event in the console. This is because the `HTML` belongs to a component that was created by Angular.

If you were to type in the cloned input, it would **not** print in the console. This is because while the `HTML` is valid, there is no component instance that is connected to it, so the method is never called. We are only able to clone the `HTML` not the component.

If you want to create multiple instances of `HTML` with behaviour, a.k.a. a component, the best approach would be the `*ngFor`.

Comment: Whtat if this._el.nativeElement is input element?

Comment: I need append after not inside

Comment: To append after your own element you should do `this.renderer.appendChild(original.parentNode, this.cloned)`.

Comment: Thank you, only one problem after clone element, the directive does not work on this clonned element

Comment: Like I mentioned, any type of behaviour that is done via typescript cannot be cloned. For that you need to use the `*ngFor`. Angular does not allow the addition of directives at run time yet.